# Consolidate multiple jQuery conditional statements to a single query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

On my web page, I output jQuery for each record that is rendered on the page like this:

```
if ($.trim($('#attachment<%# Eval("Id")%> .content').html()) == '') {
  $('#attachmentClick<%# Eval("Id")%>').hide();
}
```

Notice there is server binding on the element ID to make sure each record has the jQuery processed. Is there a way to do this only once on the page by embedding the conditional statement, such as "for all `$(this.ID + ' .attachmentsClick')`, hide only if `$('.attachments.content').html()` trimmed is blank"?

Comment: I've read your question several times and still don't understand what you mean about the ID. I think you might be saying "on the server, I decide if a record is processed (whatever that means), and if so, I give it an ID attribute (matching its ID in the database, maybe?)." So are you saying that your jQuery will look for items that have an ID attribute, but each one will be a different ID? If so, `$('div[id]')` would find divs that have any ID. Then again, `this.ID` makes it sound like you'll use the ID as a class. Can you clarify?

Comment: Actually... I think I may have misunderstood your question. Is the thing that you want to hide the parent of the "content" element? That's what I had assumed when I first read your question. If I have misunderstood, could you post your HTML so that I can correct my answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [jQuery's filter function](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to reduce the set of potential elements to those with empty content, and then hide them:

```
$('.attachmentsClick').filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).find('.content').html()) == '';
}).hide();
```

This assumes that you give the class of "attachmentsClick" to all of your row elements. It does not need the ID of the row elements. Just run this after your content has loaded, and it will hide all elements with a class of "attachmentsClick" that have a child with a class of "content" which is empty when trimmed.

Your HTML might look something like:

```
<div class="attachmentsClick"><!-- this one will be hidden -->
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>

<div class="attachmentsClick"><!-- this one will be hidden too -->
  <div class="content">     </div>
</div>

<div class="attachmentsClick"><!-- this one will NOT be hidden -->
  <div class="content"><p>some content<p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this a lot better than `each`!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.each()`.  `.someCommonClass` should be on each one that has the ID.

```
$('.someCommonClass').each(function(i, e) {
   var $e = $(e);
   if ($.trim($('.content', $e).html()) == '')
       $e.hide();
});
```